# go - golang compile error: type has no method

Tags: go

how to solve it?
https://play.golang.org/p/aOrqmDM91J

> :28: Cache.Segment undefined (type Cache has no method Segment)
>
> :29: Cache.Segment undefined (type Cache has no method Segment)

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Slot struct {  
    Key []string
    Val []string
}

type Cache struct{
    Segment [3615]Slot
}

func NewCache(s int) *Cache{
    num:=3615
    Cacheobj:=new(Cache)
    
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        Cacheobj.Segment[i].Key = make([]string, s)
        Cacheobj.Segment[i].Val = make([]string, s)
    }
            
    return Cacheobj
}

func (*Cache)Set(k string, v string) {
        for mi, mk := range Cache.Segment[0].Key {
         fmt.Println(Cache.Segment[0].Val[mi])  
    }
}
func main() {
    Cache1:=NewCache(100)
    Cache1.Set("a01", "111111")
}
```

Comment: Since links can go stale/change over time, it's best to include your code directly into your post.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

`Cache` is a type. To call a method on a `Cache` object you have to do this.

```
func (c *Cache) Set(k string, v string) {
    for mi, _ := range c.Segment[0].Key {
         fmt.Println(c.Segment[0].Val[mi])  
    }
}
```

Note its `c.Segment[0].Key` and `c.Segment[0].Val[mi]` instead of `Cache.Segment[0].Key` and `Cache.Segment[0].Val[mi]`

<kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/p9Euelj1q6)</kbd>

**unrelated suggestion:** Run [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) on your code. It points to violations of regularly followed style guidelines for go code. I notice a few on your code.

Answer (score -2):

You need to give a variable to *Cache to use it, something like:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Slot struct {  
    Key []string
    Val []string
}

type Cache struct{
    Segment [3615]Slot
}

func NewCache(s int) *Cache{
    num:=3615
    Cacheobj:=new(Cache)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        Cacheobj.Segment[i].Key = make([]string, s)
        Cacheobj.Segment[i].Val = make([]string, s)
    }

    return Cacheobj
}

func (c *Cache)Set(k string, v string) {
        for mi, _:= range c.Segment[0].Key { // Had to change mk to _ because go will not compile when variables are declared and unused
         fmt.Println(c.Segment[0].Val[mi])  
    }
}
func main() {
    Cache1:=NewCache(100)
    Cache1.Set("a01", "111111")
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/1vLwVZrX20